# multi node cassandra cluster - load_balancing_policy

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Hi have some issue to connect my cassandra from my python connector

Connotor.py contain below code

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra import ReadTimeout
import os

class CassandraConnection():

    def getConnection():
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username ='admin', password='Dog2019')
        cluster=Cluster(['a5ad8e558c23e9a524-1196365.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com'], auth_provider=auth_provider)

        session = cluster.connect()
        session.set_keyspace('tonnage')
        cluster.connect()

        return session
```

While run my python code getting this error

WARNING:

> cassandra.cluster:Cluster.**init** called with contact_points
>   specified, but no load_balancing_policy. In the next major version,
>   this will raise an error; please specify a load-balancing policy.
>   (contact_points =
>   ['a5ad8e558c23e9a524-1196365.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com'], lbp =
>   None)

WARNING:

> cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 100.100.0.3,
>   scheduling retry in 4.0 seconds: [Errno None] Tried connecting to
>   [('100.100.0.3', 9042)]. Last error: timed out

WARNING:

> cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 100.100.0.2,
>   scheduling retry in 128.0 seconds: [Errno None] Tried connecting to
>   [('100.100.0.2', 9042)]. Last error: timed out

WARNING:

> cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 100.100.0.2,
>   scheduling retry in 4.0 seconds: [Errno None] Tried connecting to
>   [('100.100.0.2', 9042)]. Last error: timed out

INFO:cassandra.policies:Using datacenter 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (via host '34.217.153.0'); if incorrect, please specify a local_dc to the constructor, or limit contact points to local cluster nodes
INFO:cassandra.cluster:New Cassandra host  discovered
INFO:cassandra.cluster:New Cassandra host  discovered
INFO:cassandra.cluster:Cassandra host 52.26.34.69 removed

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for this error is following (I'm not 100% sure as we need more information about your setup) - you're pointing to the load balancer as contact point, this name is resolved to the multiple IP addresses that belong to the Cassandra nodes in the different Cassandra data centers. Usually it's not a recommended setup  - you need to point to nodes instead.  You can still use IP addresses of nodes in different data centers, but in that case you need to pass the `local_dc` parameter to `Cluster` constructor (as it's said in the last message).

Another problem that is seen in the messages, is that some of the nodes are announcing the private AWS addresses instead of using public IP addresses for broadcast (as [described here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configSnitchEC2MultiRegion.html)).

Comment: I have configured cassandra cluster using  BITNAMI CASSANDRA STACK HELM CHARTS [Cassandra] (https://bitnami.com/stack/cassandra/containers)